# Pandas - applying groupings and counts to multiple columns in order to generate/change a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm sure what I'm trying to do is fairly simple for those with better knowledge of PD, but I'm simply stuck at transforming:

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| Trigger |    Date    | Value |
+---------+------------+-------+
|    1    | 01/01/2016 |   a   |
+---------+------------+-------+
|    2    | 01/01/2016 |   b   |
+---------+------------+-------+
|    3    | 01/01/2016 |   c   |
+---------+------------+-------+

...etc, into:

+------------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
|   Date     |  #of triggers       | count a | count b | count c |
+------------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 01/01/2016 | 3                   |    1    |    1    |     1   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+
| 02/01/2016 | 5                   |    2    |    1    |     2   |
+------------+---------------------+---------+---------+---------+

... and so on
```

The issue is, I've got no bloody idea of how to achieve this..
I've scoured SO, but I can't seem to find anything that applies to my specific case.

I presume I'd have to group it all by date, but then once that is done, what do I need to do to get the remaining columns?

The initial DF is loaded from an SQL Alchemy query object, and then I want to manipulate it to get the result I described above. How would one do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), also parameter `sort=False` is helpful:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date','Value'])['Value'].size().unstack(fill_value=0)
df1['Total'] = df1.sum(axis=1)
cols = df1.columns[-1:].union(df1.columns[:-1])
df1 = df1[cols]
print (df1)
Value       Total  a  b  c
Date                      
01/01/2016      3  1  1  1
```

> The difference between `size` and `count` is:
>   [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) counts `NaN` values, [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count) does not.

Comment: Appreciate the solution, but this covers counting the a,b and c values, how would one slap the count of triggers alongside so the output includes it?

Comment: I think the easiest is use `sum`, then I reorder columns also. Please check my solution.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(['Date','Value']).count().unstack(level=-1)
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't choose your answer, but I preferred the fact that jezrael took the time to explain a little.